# Organizing non-Maven source code in Eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, ide

I am working with some sample source code that comes with a book that I recently purchased.  This sample source code does not use Maven.  When I imported the sample source code into Eclipse, it created a zillion new projects, cluttering my Project Explorer.  I want to organize all the source code from the book under one Master project, whose name is derived from the book.  After playing around quite a bit, I came up with a working solution that is reproduced below:

1. Created a Maven project, choosing the book title as the Artifact Id
   {thereby organizing all the child projects under the book title}
2. In the Maven project, created multiple directories **from Eclipse**,
   one for each chapter of the book `(New --> New Folder --> Folder name)` {this ensures that Eclipse has visibility to the directories}
3. Closed Eclipse
4. Copied the source code, chapter by chapter, to each of the directories created under the Maven project
5. Relaunched Eclipse
6. Sequentially imported the projects from each directory created under the Maven project directory in Step #2 (`Import --> General --> Projects from Folder or Archive`)

Although I have been able to realize my goal, I am uncomfortable with the fact that I am creating the Maven project solely for the purpose of organizing multiple non-Maven projects under one parent project.  I am not making any use of neat Maven features like dependency management.

---

> Q)  What is the best way to organize multiple non-Maven projects under one parent project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if these projects are all test projects unrelated to other projects, you can just create a new Workspace in Eclipse.

If this is not what you want, you can define Working Sets that organise projects.

It is usually not necessary to put projects into subfolders to organise them.

Comment: Making use of Project Explorers ability to deal with projects in subfolders is now recommended - at least for Eclipse RCP projects using Tycho (see for example parts of [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html))